# How to get full page height includes the content that I can see with using of scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with content height more than window height. I need to get with help of jQuery or pure Javascript a full height of my page. How to get this value?

I thought about

```
$('body height')+$('body').scrollTop();
```

But this solution returns the full height only when I scrolled page to bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).height()` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/height/)) should do what you want. You can also get the height of the `<body>` tag with `$('body').height()`, which should be the full height of the page.

Comment: $(document).height() returns height equal window height. Without content that available with help of sscrolling.

Comment: @user3775292 see the update - it provides an alternative as `$(document).height()` may not be consistent across all browsers :-)

Comment: I try it, but I get height without hidden area.

Comment: @user3775292 What's your page? Give us a link, because these should work in most cases

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
$(document).height(); // Get's the height of the HTML Document
```

Because this..

```
$(window).height(); // get's only the height of the Viewport...
```

Greetings

Comment: I get only height of visible area when I use $(document).height();

Comment: I've tried it on my test page and it seems to work. But this could be a bug in other browsers. Try $('body').height() which @Joe has mentioned above.